# Auto tab not working, can’t find the next instance of same class

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble doing to auto tab on the inputs.  I am trying to find the next instance of the same class for but I am not sure what i am doing wrong here.

Can someone advise me here please?

jsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/zincy/g8urecma/

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="pin-code" type="password" maxlength="1" class="pin-input">
    <label for="pin-code">Password input</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="pin-code" type="password" maxlength="1" class="pin-input">
    <label for="pin-code">Password input</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="pin-code" type="password" maxlength="1" class="pin-input">
    <label for="pin-code">Password input</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="pin-code" type="password" maxlength="1" class="pin-input">
    <label for="pin-code">Password input</label>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="show-password">Show/Hide
    <i class="icon-hide-password"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
    $(".pin-input").keyup(function () {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');

  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    var $next = $(this).parent().next('.input-container').find('.pin-input');

    if ($next.length) {
      $(this).next('.pin-input').focus();
    }

    else {
      $(this).blur();

    }

  }
});
```

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: thanks, i changed the IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already correctly found the next `.pin-input` so use that variable.

So instead of

```
if ($next.length) {
  $(this).next('.pin-input').focus();
}
```

use

```
if ($next.length) {
  $next.focus();
}
```

---

```js
$(".pin-input").keyup(function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');

  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    var $next = $(this).parent().next('.input-container').find('.pin-input');

    if ($next.length) {
      $next.focus();
    } else {
      $(this).blur();

    }

  }
});
```

```css
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

label { font-size: 0;}
.input-container {
  display:inline-block;
 
  }
  .pin-input{
     width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  text-align: center
  }
  .container{
    width: 530px;
  }
  .show-password {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  
  .fa {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="pin-code" type="password" maxlength="1" class="pin-input">
    <label for="pin-code">Password input</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="pin-code" type="password" maxlength="1" class="pin-input">
    <label for="pin-code">Password input</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="pin-code" type="password" maxlength="1" class="pin-input">
    <label for="pin-code">Password input</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="pin-code" type="password" maxlength="1" class="pin-input">
    <label for="pin-code">Password input</label>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="show-password">Show/Hide
    <i class="icon-hide-password"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```